# Colour & Size Issue After STL image Import in Processing

Tags: image-processing, 3d, processing, windows-7-x64, stl-format

I wrote a program in Processing, to import a STL file and then rotate in 3D according to requirement.

But I am facing a problem that the import image is very colorful and small in size. it looks very different from original.

Can you please help me to resolve this problem.
Coding and images are given below

```
import toxi.geom.*;
import toxi.geom.mesh.*;

import toxi.processing.*;

TriangleMesh mesh;
ToxiclibsSupport gfx;

void setup() {
  size(displayWidth, displayHeight,P3D);
  mesh=(TriangleMesh)new STLReader().loadBinary(sketchPath("check.stl"),STLReader.TRIANGLEMESH);
  gfx=new ToxiclibsSupport(this);
}

void draw() {
  background(51);
  translate(width/2,height/2,0);
  rotateX(mouseY*0.01);
  rotateY(mouseX*0.01);

  gfx.mesh(mesh,false);
}
```

[image: Result I am Getting]
[image: Result which I desire]

Comment: Crossposted: http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/9772/colour-issue-after-exportation-of-stl-image

Comment: Do you get the same results if you *don't* do the rotation?

Comment: @MarkRansom No, I always get result like Picture 1, but my desire result is Picture 2

Comment: @IrfanGhaffar7 Please read this: http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/BeForthrightWhenCrossPostingToOtherSites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had same confusion like you but after scrolling [reference page](https://processing.org/reference/) of `Processing.org` 
I found couple of commands which can effected on STL Object in positive way.
some command are:

1. directionalLight
2. nostroke
3. scale

Increases or decreases the size of a shape by expanding and contracting vertices

Your above issue is directly linked with these commands so just edit it according to your requirement

```
import toxi.geom.*;
import toxi.geom.mesh.*;
import toxi.processing.*;

TriangleMesh mesh;
ToxiclibsSupport gfx;

void setup() {
  size(displayHeight, displayWidth,P3D);
  mesh=(TriangleMesh)new STLReader().loadBinary(sketchPath("check.stl"),STLReader.TRIANGLEMESH);
  gfx=new ToxiclibsSupport(this);

}

void draw() {

  background(51);
  translate(width/2,height/2,0);
  rotateX(mouseY*0.01);
  rotateY(mouseX*0.01);
  directionalLight(192, 168, 128,0, -1000, -0.5);
  directionalLight(255, 64, 0, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.1f);
  noStroke();
scale(3);  
  gfx.mesh(mesh,false);
}
```

image after program running[image]